# show.progress in readr and knitr

Tags: rstudio, r-markdown, knitr, readr

I am currently working on a .Rmd notebook, RStudio version 1.1.442.

Following the `Knitr` manual and different examples found also in various vignette, in my notebook I've asked `readr` (installed version: 1.1.1) not to show progress bar using a hidden code blok:

````
```{r global_opts, echo=FALSE}
options(readr.show_progress = FALSE)
```
````

Without this specification, the document is annoyingly rendered with each percentual step of `readr` progress bar (if I remember correctly, once, the rendering process returned just the 'Parsed with column specification' message).

Already tried:

- Setting in the chunck options `results='hide'` or `echo = FALSE`: these options do not fit my needs, as they suppress also the column specification;
- Setting chunk option `warning=FALSE` does not suppress col specification nor the progress bar printing;

From the **Chunk Options** section in the [RStudio's *RMarkdown* website](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/lesson-3.html):

> - `include = FALSE` prevents code and results from appearing in the finished file. R Markdown still runs the code in the chunk, and the results can be used by other chunks.
> - `echo = FALSE` prevents code, but not the results from appearing in the finished file. This is a useful way to embed figures.
> - `message = FALSE` prevents messages that are generated by code from appearing in the finished file.
> - `warning = FALSE` prevents warnings that are generated by code from appearing in the finished.

I am looking for a way to keep the progress bar in the console, without having it renderd in the final HTML/PDF rendered document.

Thanks.

Comment: I found an article that seems to deal with exactly this question, with a few different usage examples: https://rmflight.github.io/knitrProgressBar/articles/example_progress_bars.html They seem to indicate using some extra package for piping the progress bar output connection to some place other than stdout.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the readr function show_progress.

`read_delim("myFile", progress = show_progress())`

This will show the progress bar only when running the command in console, but not in an interactive markdown document.